# Domino Solitaire in Python

Tags: python

In Domino Solitaire, you have a grid with two rows and many columns. Each square in the grid contains an integer. You are given a supply of rectangular 2 × 1 tiles, each of which exactly covers two adjacent squares of the grid. You have to place tiles to cover all the squares in the grid such that each tile covers two squares and no pair of tiles overlap.

The score for a tile is the difference between the bigger and the smaller number that are covered by the tile. The aim of the game is to maximize the sum of the scores of all the tiles.

Here is an example of a grid, along with two different tilings and their scores.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmqTO.png)

The score for Tiling 1 is 12 = (9−8)+(6−2)+(7−1)+(3−2) while the score for Tiling 2 is 6 = (8−6)+(9−7)+(3−2)+(2−1). There are other tilings possible for this grid, but you can check that Tiling 1 has the maximum score among all tilings.

Your task is to read the grid of numbers and compute the maximum score that can be achieved by any tiling of the grid.

My Solution of above problem is this

```
n = int(input())
l = [input().split() for j in range(0, 2)]
b = [0 for i in range(0, n)]


b[0] = int(l[0][1]) - int(l[0][0])
b[1] = max(b[0] + abs(int(l[1][0]) - int(l[1][1])), abs(int(l[1][0]) - int(l[0][0])) + abs(int(l[1][1]) - int(l[0][1])))

for i in range(2, n):
    x = b[i-1] + abs(int(l[i][0]) - int(l[i][1]))
    y = b[i-2] + abs(int(l[i][0]) - int(l[i-1][0])) + abs(int(l[i][1]) - int(l[i-1][1]))
    b[i] = max(x, y)

print(b[n-1])
```

But it gives me error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python Programs/StringFromating/stringformat.py", line 10, in <module>
    x = b[i-1] + abs(int(l[i][0]) - int(l[i][1]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: I'm confused by the whole problem and the code, but I know that `b` is an int because you set it to an int here: `b = max(...)`. I can't tell you how to _fix_ it, because I'm not sure what that line of code is supposed to do, but that's where the problem is.

Comment: You have redefined `b`, and that's what's causing error (as @Aran-Fey said). Just use different names.

Answer (score 2):

Well, reading your code i saw something.

```
x = b[i-1] + abs(int(l[i][0]) - int(l[i][1]))
```

You seem to accessing l[i][0] where i is n (at max). But l has n columns and only two rows.

After trying to form a logic, i suggest you revise the whole program with this in mind. Could be beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

```
#My solution to the above problem :
n=int(input())
arr=list(map(int,input().split()))
arr_2=list(map(int,input().split()))
prev_state=0
final =abs(arr[0]-arr_2[0])
for i in range(1,n):
  vertical_place = final + abs(arr[i]-arr_2[i])
  horizontal_place = prev_state + abs(arr[i] - arr[i-1]) + abs(arr_2[i] - arr_2[i-1])
  prev_state = final
  final = max(vertical_place,horizontal_place)
print(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

## My take on the above problem

```
n = input()

line1 = input()
line2 = input()

input_data=[[],[]]

temp_1 = line1.split(" ")
temp_2 = line2.split(" ")

for element in temp_1:
    try:
        input_data[0].append(int(element))
    except ValueError:
        pass
for element in temp_2:
    try:
        input_data[1].append(int(element))
    except ValueError:
        pass
    

lookup_table = {}

def arrangements(n,a):
    
    try:
        if lookup_table[n]:
            return(lookup_table[n])
    except:
        pass
    

    diff_1 =  a[0][0]-a[1][0]
    value = abs(diff_1)
    lookup_table[1] = value

    
    diff_2_vertical   = abs(a[0][0]-a[1][0]) + abs(a[0][1]-a[1][1])
    diff_2_horizontal = abs(a[0][0]-a[0][1]) + abs(a[1][0]-a[1][1])
        
    value = max(diff_2_vertical,diff_2_horizontal)
    lookup_table[2] = value
        
    
    
    for i in range(3,n+1):
    
        diff_vertical = abs(a[0][i-1]-a[1][i-1])
        
        
        
        sum_vertical_start = diff_vertical + lookup_table[i-1] 
        
        diff_horizontal = abs(a[0][i-1]-a[0][i-2]) + abs(a[1][i-1]-a[1][i-2])
        
        
        sum_horizontal_start = diff_horizontal + lookup_table[i-2] 
        value = max(sum_vertical_start,sum_horizontal_start)
        lookup_table[i] = value
        
    
    
    return(lookup_table[n])
```